# Creating Connection Method Within The Class Is Valid or Not in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, database-connection

I am developing an application using Swing, so before starting up I need to know a few basics regarding working with `Connection`. In many tutorials, I have seen that we need to create a `connection` `Class` and get the connection within the project using `getConnection()`.

But I have created a `connectionMethod` is it possible to get the connection in my entire project by creating `object` of the connection class and using the connection?

This is my code:

```
package ncl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Test {

    Connection connection=null;
    public void connectionMethod() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test","sa", "");  

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Test().connectionMethod();

        try {

            // DO STUFF HERE

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally {
            try {
                new Test().connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I want to know whether this approach is good or not.

Comment: No it isn't good. You are creating an instance of `Test` and throw it away, then you create another instance of test which doesn't have a connection (it's `null`).

Comment: can you help me with this @Mark Rotteveel

Answer (score 1):

This totally depends on the practitioner that how he/she wants to code. Ideally we should follow [Design Patterns](https://www.javatpoint.com/design-patterns-in-java) in implementation to achieve many properties like *Low Coupling*, *High Cohesion* etc.

You told that in many tutorials, they make separate class which only provides connection. It is a good practice to avoid the problem of *dependency* and we can allocate *responsibility* to the classes in more efficient way. So you should also do it by creating new class which only provides the connection.

For the mentioned code, you have made some mistakes. You have first taken an instance of `Test` class which has `connection` and you didn't assign it to any variable. So you can't use it further when you need the connection. Another mistake is that you try to close the connection by creating another instance of `Test` class which obviously doesn't have started connection.

So, you can make appropriate suggested changes.

**ConnectionFactory.java :**

This will provide the connection objects.

```
package ncl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionFactory {

    Connection connection=null;
    public void connectionMethod() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test","sa", "");  

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

**Test.java :**

Write the actual code here.

```
package ncl;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ConnectionFactory connectionObject = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionObject.connectionMethod();

        try {

            // DO STUFF HERE

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally {
            try {
                connectionObject.connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below utility class :

```
public class MyConnection {

    private Connection con = null;

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            if (con == null) {
                Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;
    }
}
```

For getting connection you can call **MyConnection().getConnection();**
For example :
If you want to get connection in any class then do the following :

```
Connection con = new MyConnection().getConnection();
```